# Insert calculated values between consecutive values in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have a simple array, like this one:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3])
```

Which returns me, obviously:

```
array([1, 2, 3])
```

I'm trying to add calculated values between consecutive values in this array. The calculation should return me `n` equally spaced values between it's bounds.

To express myself in numbers, let's say I want to add `1` value between each pair of consecutive values, so the function should return me a array like this:

```
array([1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3])
```

Another example, now with `2` values between each pair:

```
array([1, 1.33, 1.66, 2, 2.33, 2.66, 3])
```

I know the logic and I can create myself a function which will do the work, but I feel numpy has specific functions that would make my code so much cleaner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array is

```
import numpy as np

n = 2
a = np.array([1,2,5])

new_size = a.size + (a.size - 1) * n

x = np.linspace(a.min(), a.max(), new_size)
xp = np.linspace(a.min(), a.max(), a.size)
fp = a
result = np.interp(x, xp, fp)
```

returns: `array([1.        , 1.33333333, 1.66666667, 2.        , 2.66666667, 3.33333333, 4.        ])`

If your array is always evenly spaced, you can just use

```
new_size = a.size + (a.size - 1) * n
result = np.linspace(a.min(), a.max(), new_size)
```

Comment: Fantastic! You even predicted the problem I didn't know I had

Answer (score 0):

Using [linspace](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) should do the trick:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
n = 1

temps = []

for i in range(1, len(a)):
    temps.append(np.linspace(a[i-1], a[i], num=n+1, endpoint=False))

# Add last final ending point
temps.append(np.array([a[-1]]))
new_a = np.concatenate(temps)
print(new_a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `np.arange`:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
n = 2
print(np.arange(a.min(), a.max(), 1 / (n + 1)))
```

Output:

```
[1.         1.33333333 1.66666667 2.         2.33333333 2.66666667]
```